# Syntax file sourced from the plugin is overwritten by Vim

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I am creating a very simple plugin to make syntax highlighting better in Vim for baan syntax (basically an improved version of syntax/baan.vim).

This is my plugin directory.
[image]

One file inside ftdetect folder; baan.vim. It looks like this.

```
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.bc set filetype=baan
```

The file inside syntax folder; baan.vim. It is almost the same as baan.vim in syntax folder within Vim. With one line of change in syntax highlighting.

My problem is when I open any files with .bc extensions, two more syntax files are called; one before my own plugin syntax file, and other one is after.

[image]

bc.vim syntax file is called already from filetyp.vim, I guess. Because filetypes I want to set syntax is with extension .bc. This is the first issue. Second one is that I set filetype to 'baan' but Vim is looking and sourcing all baan.vim files. But once baan.vim is source from myplugin, it is still sourcing the one from Vim itself. How can I solve those issues elegantly without using /after directory?

Comment: This seems normal and expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal. Consider the following.

1. `$VIMRUNTIME/filetype.vim` sources `ftdetect/*.vim` scripts near to the end. At this point `setf bc` was already executed and the first `FileType` event was triggered and processed. BTW. This is the reason why late `set ft=baan` works but `setf baan` no more. Shouldn't be a problem though, as `:syn clear` is executed in `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/synload.vim` automatically. And no, you can't do anything with this unless you patch/replace `filetype.vim`.
2. `synload.vim` intentionally sources all matching files (`:runtime!`). This is the reason they respect `b:current_syntax` variable. The first to set it wins, others step aside by executing `:finish` at a top. Nonetheless, they all are sourced and get into `:scriptnames`. Note this also means that extending existing syntax with `after/syntax` (while not respecting `b:current_syntax`) is usually more preferable.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. In my understanding, although bc.vim syntax is called, filetype is overwritten with set ft=baan. So, syntax file is forced to be overwritten with my plugin syntax file, which is fine. For the second issue, I guess since plugin syntax file is executed first, final syntax file (syntax/baan.vim) is not executed because of early return via :finish. I can also confirm that, my syntax highlighting works as expected. The fact that files can be sourced in Vim startup does not mean that their content will be fully executed. Now it is more clear to me.

Comment: Maybe one last question; If want to keep track of b:current_syntax variable, is that possible?

Comment: @EnisArik I don't get what you want to achieve. Normally it is only set by syntax scripts that are sourced upon `Syntax` event.